# SQL relationship issues

Tags: sql

I'm creating an app that will search a table called `tags` for events tagged with those tags. There will be two tables: `tags` and `events`, and when a user searches for something, the app searches the `tags` table and then displays information for the relevant information from the `events` table.

This is the flow of how the application will search and display data:

```
User searches -> 
SQL search on tags table -> 
using tag_ids found, search for relevant events on events table -> 
display event data
```

Am I thinking about this the correct way? I have a feeling I might not be. I don't want to store each of the `tag_ids` in columns named `tag_id_1`, `tag_id_2`, etc. on the `events` table, and I don't want to limit the number of tags that a user can have attached to an event. However, I don't want to rely on my application to do major processing of the SQL, so I don't want to store the tags as a `JSON` object in the table either. Is this possible, or will I have to change how I search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have here an N:N relationship. There are multiple types of tags that can be added to multiple different events. You need to create another table to link those together: a `tags_per_event` table, for example.

In the `tags` table you store only information about the tags themselves (id, description..). In the `events` table you only describe events (id, description, source...). Finally, in the `tags_per_event` table you have one row for each tag for each event. For each row, you will have the ID of the tag and the ID of the event. When you lookup the information, you need to join the 3 table in order to get all the information about which tags were assigned to which event and what is the information you have on those (adding descriptions and such).

[image]

Comment: And you could just do `join` statements between all three tables, correct?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you need one more table. You already have TAGS and EVENTS, but TAGS shouldn't be included in the EVENTS table, so create a TAGS_EVENTS table, with one row for every TAG_ID and EVENT_ID.

- TAGS TABLE

  ```
  ID | NAME 
  1  | sql 
  2  | oracle
  ```
- EVENTS TABLE

  ```
  ID | TYPE 
  1  | Question asked 
  2  | Question asked
  ```
- TAGS_EVENTS TABLE

  ```
  EVENT_ID | TAG_ID 
  1        | 1 
  1        | 2
  2        | 2
  ```

EXPLANATION:

- EVENT 1: Question asked with tags "sql" and "oracle"
- EVENT 2: Question asked with tag "oracle"